# Number density of LO and LA phonons as a function of temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, specific-reference, solid-state-physics, phonons

I'd like to know the how the number density of longitudinal optical (LO) and longitudinal acoustic (LA) [phonons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) varies as a function of temperature of the material. Is there a simple expression for these two cases?

I'm guessing that this would work,

$N_{LO} = \int g_{LO}(E) f(E, T) dE$

$N_{LA} = \int g_{LA}(E) f(E, T) dE$

where $g(E)$ is the density of states for LO and LA phonons and $f$ is the Bose-Einstein distribution. What would be appropriate limits for the integrals. Does anybody know a reference where the density of states for these two modes is given?

**EDIT**

To improve the question, I'm interested in semiconductor 3D crystals. But maybe I left this too long, sorry.

Best regards,

Comment: Sure seems right to me. Of course thee Bose-Einstein distribution allows occupation numbers greater than one.

Comment: Question number one: do you want experimental or theoretical results? Question number two: what kind of materials? Pure crystals, crystals with defects, arbitrary solids?

Comment: @Marek; It seems to me that the equations should work irrespective of the material. Can you correct me on this? I'm thinking that they would simply have different $g(E)$.

Comment: @Carl: are you saying the temperature dependence for *any* material is only present in the Bose-Einstein part of the formula? This statement seems quite unobvious and is probably wrong too.

Comment: @Marek; Oh no, I see what you mean. Yes, of course there will be T dependence on both.

Comment: @Carl: right. But I still don't understand what OP is after. Whether after theoretical derivation of $g$ based on some toy model, or experimental data on $g$ for some class of materials.

Comment: It's never too late to try for an answer ;-)

Comment: I think that optical phonons are all too high frequency to have appreciable excitations at normal temperatures (since they are _optically_ excited, so they requires a temperature which has visible Planck radiation), and you can just look up the standard Debye spectrum for the long-wavelength acoustic phonons at temperature T. Your expression is correct, but the density of states of optical phonons is only nonzero very far away from zero energy, while acoustic phonons have a powerlaw density of states near zero energy, so they get Debye spectrum.

Comment: @RonMaimon - phonons up to 25 meV can be excited by thermal energies, so there is an appreciable contribution to the phonon DOS at room temperature from optical phonons.  Further, the "optical" in optical phonon results from the coupling of light to the oscillating dipole moment of the involved ions allowing their detection - not solely the ability to be activated by light.  Further, "optical" is used more generally to characterize "not-acoustic," so even non-Raman-active modes bear this moniker.

Comment: "What are appropriate limits for these integrals?" You seem to be thinking that there are phonon frequencies all the way from 0 to infinity? Actually, they only span a finite range, i.e. each type of crystal has a finite maximum phonon frequency. You should integrate over that whole finite range. (Of course, you are entitled to ignore a part of the range if g*f is sufficiently close to zero there.)

Comment: Every time Community brings this back to the front page I hear the *Doors* singing their hit single "LA Phonon".

Comment: @SteveB Yes, after a few years away I now appreciate that there is a maximum frequency of phonons (those at the zone edge) :) So I think that imposes the limits in the above equation. Thank you. At higher frequencies zone folding will occur which gives higher energy bands. To calculate the number density is is valid to integrate only over one unit cell?

Comment: @boyfarrell - Again, each type of crystal has a finite maximum phonon frequency. The highest frequency phonon is usually one of the optical phonons at k=0, although it might be at a different k in some crystals. There are NOT infinitely many phonon bands at higher and higher frequencies. (This is the case for electron bands but not phonon bands.) The number of phonon bands is related to the number of atoms in a unit cell.

Comment: @SteveB yes of course, I know that (error in my last comment). What I really wanted to say was that I appreciate why there is a upper a lower limit on the integration. Thank you for the insight regarding zone folding, that wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Different types of phonons can not be considered as separate systems. They are oscillations of the same crystal and interact with each-other.

For example, LO phonon lifetime is about $10^{-12}$ - $10^{-11}$ seconds while the period of the oscillations is about $10^{-13}$ seconds (GaAs). At the end it turns into two LA phonons that run opposite directions.

Bose-Einstein distribution describes thermodynamical equilibrium of the whole phonon system. You should integrate over all the modes.

The density of states can be estimated numerically or measured experimentally.  Both usually give similar results that can be found e.g. in chapter 3 of ["Fundamentals of Semiconductors" by Peter Y. Yu and Manuel Cardona](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Fundamentals_of_Semiconductors.html?id=5aBuKYBT_hsC&redir_esc=y).

The main experimental techniques are

- neutron scattering
- scattering of "hard" X-rays
- [Raman spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_spectroscopy).

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but if the interaction is weak enough (as I believe it will be for this case), you can describe the optical phonons and the acoustic phonons both with separate Bose-Einstein distributions for free fields and not be too far off. The question is not whether they interact, but whether the average energy of an optical phonon in the thermal background of acoustic phonons is going to be changed significantly (and vice versa). My impulse is that opticals are absent at reasonable temperature, while long-wavelength acoustic phonons have a near-perfect Debye spectrum.

Comment: @Maksim, Would suggest that you include neutron scattering with appropriate application of the incoherent approximation rather than solely Raman spectroscopy, since not all optical phonon modes are Raman-active.

Comment: @RonMaimon, I have never heard anything about quasi-equilibrium state of optical phonons. In order to let this equilibrium exist there should be some mechanism of LO phonon - LO phonon interaction with characteristic time much shorter then the decay time. This is an interesting question.

Answer (score 2):

LA phonons have $$E=\hbar\omega=\hbar c k$$ where $c$ is the speed of (longitudinal) sound, and so have a density of states exactly like that of photons (with a different value of she speed, and a factor of 1/2 as there is only one polarization states) e.g. $$g(E)=V(\hbar c)^{-3}2^{-1}\pi^{-2} E^2$$ and this is only rigorously true for low values of $k$ or $E$.  And, there are only $N$ modes.  A common model is to assume that there are only the number of $k$'s so that there are $N$ models but that the form for $g$ is otherwise exact.  This "Debye" model is explained reasonably well on wikipedia.

LO phonons are a different story.  Here the simple model is that the have a single frequency and there are $N$ of them, that is a more-or-less Einstein model (also explained on wikipedia.)